# Which is an advantage of storing images directly in MongoDB instead of serverside folder

Tags: mongodb

I suppose that storing images (or any binary data - pdfs, movies, etc. ) outside of DB (MongoDB in my case) and putting them in public server folder can be at least faster (no encoding, decoding and things around that).

But since there is such an option in MondoDB, I'd like to know advantages of using this, and use cases, when that approach is recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Replication: It is pretty easy to set up a highly available replica set. So even if one machine goes down, the files would still be available. While this is possible to achieve by various means for a simple filesystem as well, the overhead for this might well eliminate the performance advantage (if there is any: MongoDB has quite sophisticated internal caching going on). Furthermore, setting up a DRBD and making sure consistency and availability requires quite more knowledge and administrative effort than with MongoDB. Plus, you'd need to have your DB be highly available as well.
2. Scalability: It can get quite complicated and/or costly when your files exceed the storage capacity of a single node. While in theory you can scale vertically, there is a certain point where the bang you get for the buck decreases and scaling horizontally makes more sense. However, with a filesystem approach, you'd have to manage which file is located at which node, how and when to balance and whatnot. MongoDB's GridFS in a sharded environment does this for you automatically and – more important – transparently. You neither have to reinvent the wheel nor maintain it.
3. Query by metadata: While in theory you can do this by an approach with a database and links to a filesystem, GridFS comes with means to insert arbitrary metadata and query by it. Again, this saves you reinventing the wheel. As an interesting example is that finding duplicates is quite easy with GridFS: a hash sum is automatically calculated for each file in GridFS. With a rather simple aggregation, you can find dupes and then deal with them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. If I get you right, pros of using GridFS are beating pros of using conventional, relatively easy, traditional and probably already outdated approach with server fs? If so, where the balance lays this days?

Answer (score 1):

When you have large amount of binary data and you want to take advantage of sharding, you can go with storing the binary data in mongo db using gridfs.  But from performance point of view, Obviously as you pointed storing the images in a file system is a better way.